# Get data by using a query from a website

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Using Python or R, how can the following website's data be downloaded into a dataframe or similar format? I assume this is not web scraping, but rather making a request to GET the data using a query.

https://www.michigantrafficcrashfacts.org/querytool/lists/0#q1;0;2016;;

Comment: I don't understand why, but people are downvoting this question like crazy. I guess this question does not meet the high level of people are at this site. And then you are cast like the devil.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need to make web scraper, i observed all requests to that site, and then I decoded those requests with my tools...., see:

1) https://www.michigantrafficcrashfacts.org/qjson?q=1;0;2016;;&v=list&p=0,0:0,77|0|90|0,asc:1,asc   || 90 Records as json

2) https://www.michigantrafficcrashfacts.org/qjson?q=1;0;2016;;&v=list&p=0,0:0,77|0|2000|0,asc:1,asc
    ||  2000 Records as json

```
import json, requests

your_records = 3000  # change this record with that number you want ( that website said the max value is 312172 )

URL = "https://www.michigantrafficcrashfacts.org/qjson?q=1;0;2016;;&v=list&p=0,0:0,77|0|{0}|0,asc:1,asc".format(your_records)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

get_data = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

raw_data = str(get_data.content, encoding="utf-8")

dict_data = json.loads(raw_data)

for items, values in dict_data.items():
    print(items, values)
```

**NOTE : Please do not use it in illegal or hacky cases.**

Comment: Hey man, I appreciate it. This is a good starter for me. How did you come up with rest of the items in the link? When I select cols and stuff it doesn't show anything.The link still stays the same. Is there a way to show the full path in the browser, which is by default set to not showing so that it looks prettier?

Comment: @ilyas: your welcome :) did you see the first and second samples? you can open those links in your browser but full data is heavy! and i answerd your question about how can you download that website data over 90 ... for how you should pars them, or anything else, you should ask a new question, and for this special question we can not talk too much on comments box. but i should say there is no pretty link that you can use in your browser and this is not about my code or anything else, that website encypted their requests ....

Comment: @ilyas: do you know how should you work with json data?

Comment: OK Your code works. I appreciate it.  The website provides share query where it provides the query, I realized after your answer. However, there the query starts like: "michigantrafficcrashfacts.org/querytool/lists/0#q1;0;2016;;&p0,0:0,10:0,11:0,12 ....". You use a different query link. Is that something you came up on your own from your experience? How did you figure that out? When I use the provided query by the website, the last part of your code, where you use json.loads() does not work.

Comment: I mean the "qjson". The original query link doesn't have that. It has q1

Comment: Hey man. I don't understand why, but people are downvoting this question like crazy. You also are getting downvotes. Sorry for this.